# Why is $digest not getting invoked after I changed a model on $scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have an asynchronous call which is making a change a value on `$scope`.  When it completes, I don't see my view updated, but if I append a `$scope.digest()` I do see the view update.  e.g.

```
// a doesn't update in view
$rootScope.$on('some_event', function() {
    $scope.a = true;
});

// a does update in view
$rootScope.$on('some_event', function() {
    $scope.a = true;
    $scope.$digest();
});
```

According to http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/ the `$digest` cycle repeats itself until the `$scope` has settled (a minimum of two times).

Why wouldn't I see this update?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching event either by `$emit` or `$broadcast` functions call don't start digest cycle itself. Thus, if you have an event dispatched from async code like `window.setTimeout` or some third-party library, you must    use `$scope.$apply` in event handler or `$scope.$digest` in code which fire event.

Comment: Ahh, okay.  This code was indeed getting invoked by an asynchronous update. When I tried to use $apply I got an error complaining an apply was already in progress.  Is it possible my window just happened to be in the middle of an apply already?